# Jenkins buildflow job with dependency to parallel closures

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-build-flow

We have a Jenkins build flow that does this:

An initial job runs to prepare the nightly build and then N different project builds are triggered to run in parallel. For each project, one job is started to build the binaries and then a separate job is started to run tests. After all project builds and tests are finished a single job is run to analyze the results.

The final analysis contains a part that takes a long time and only depends on the binaries, not the test results. We want to run this in parallel with the test jobs to speed things up but we don't want the tests to wait for all projects to finish building the binaries. Something like this:

[image: Build flow]
The build flow is set up as an array of closures that contain each project's build and test jobs. Is it possible to add a job in each project closure that is only run if the build job in all other closures have finished? Or have a job that is waiting for a counter to reach a certain value?

Solutions using pipeline are also welcome.

Comment: I think this answer on another question is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59923355/2651243